# How can the use of C++11's 'auto' improve performance?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, auto

I can see why the `auto` type in C++11 improves correctness and maintainability. I've read that it can also improve performance ([Almost Always Auto](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) by Herb Sutter), but this part lacks a good explanation.

- How can `auto` improve performance?
- Can anyone give an example?

Comment: See http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/ which talks about avoiding accidental implicit conversions, e.g. from gadget to widget. It's not a common problem.

Comment: Do you accept “makes it less likely to unintentionally pessimize” as a performance improvement?

Comment: Perfomance of code cleaning up in the future only, maybe

Comment: We need a short answer: No if you're good. It can prevent 'noobish' mistakes. C++ has a learning curve which kills those who do not make it after all.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

`auto` can aid performance by **avoiding silent implicit conversions**. An example I find compelling is the following.

```
std::map<Key, Val> m;
// ...

for (std::pair<Key, Val> const& item : m) {
    // do stuff
}
```

See the bug? Here we are, thinking we're elegantly taking every item in the map by const reference and using the new range-for expression to make our intent clear, but actually we're copying **every** element. This is because `std::map<Key, Val>::value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, Val>`, not `std::pair<Key, Val>`. Thus, when we (implicitly) have:

```
std::pair<Key, Val> const& item = *iter;
```

Instead of taking a reference to an existing object and leaving it at that, we have to do a type conversion. You are allowed to take a const reference to an object (or temporary) of a different type as long as there is an implicit conversion available, e.g.:

```
int const& i = 2.0; // perfectly OK
```

The type conversion is an allowed implicit conversion for the same reason you can convert a `const Key` to a `Key`, but we have to construct a temporary of the new type in order to allow for that. Thus, effectively our loop does:

```
std::pair<Key, Val> __tmp = *iter;       // construct a temporary of the correct type
std::pair<Key, Val> const& item = __tmp; // then, take a reference to it
```

(Of course, there isn't actually a `__tmp` object, it's just there for illustration, in reality the unnamed temporary is just bound to `item` for its lifetime).

Just changing to:

```
for (auto const& item : m) {
    // do stuff
}
```

just saved us a ton of copies - now the referenced type matches the initializer type, so no temporary or conversion is necessary, we can just do a direct reference.

Comment: @Barry Can you explain why the compiler would happily make copies instead of complain about trying to treat an `std::pair<const Key, Val> const &` as an `std::pair<Key, Val> const &`? New to C++11, not sure how range-for and `auto` plays into this.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for the explanation. That's the piece I was missing - for some reason, I thought that you couldn't have a constant reference to a temporary. But of course you can - it'll just cease to exist at the end of its scope.

Comment: @barry I get you, but the problem is that then there isn't an answer that covers all of the reasons to use `auto` that increase performance.  So I'll write it up in my own words below.

Comment: I still don't think this is proof that "`auto` improves performance". It's just an example that "`auto` helps prevent programmer mistakes that destroy performance". I submit that there is a subtle yet important distinction between the two. Still, +1.

Answer (score 76):

Because `auto` deduces the type of the initializing expression, there is no type conversion involved. Combined with templated algorithms, this means that you can get a more direct computation than if you were to make up a type yourself – especially when you are dealing with expressions whose type you cannot name!

A typical example comes from (ab)using `std::function`:

```
std::function<bool(T, T)> cmp1 = std::bind(f, _2, 10, _1);  // bad
auto cmp2 = std::bind(f, _2, 10, _1);                       // good
auto cmp3 = [](T a, T b){ return f(b, 10, a); };            // also good

std::stable_partition(begin(x), end(x), cmp?);
```

With `cmp2` and `cmp3`, the entire algorithm can inline the comparison call, whereas if you construct a `std::function` object, not only can the call not be inlined, but you also have to go through the polymorphic lookup in the type-erased interior of the function wrapper.

Another variant on this theme is that you can say:

```
auto && f = MakeAThing();
```

This is always a reference, bound to the value of the function call expression, and never constructs any additional objects. If you didn't know the returned value's type, you might be forced to construct a new object (perhaps as a temporary) via something like `T && f = MakeAThing()`. (Moreover, `auto &&` even works when the return type is not movable and the return value is a prvalue.)

Comment: So this is "avoid type erasure" reason to use `auto`.  Your other variant is "avoid accidental copies", but needs embellishment; why does `auto` give you speed over simply typing the type there?  (I think the answer is "you get the type wrong, and it silently converts")  Which makes it a less-well explained example of Barry's answer, no?  Ie, there are two basic cases: auto to avoid type erasure, and auto to avoid silent type errors that accidentally convert, both of which have a run time cost.

Comment: "not only can the call not be inlined" -- why's that then? Do you mean that in principle something prevents the call being devirtualized after data flow analysis if the relevant specialisations of `std::bind`, `std::function` and `std::stable_partition` have all been inlined? Or just that in practice no C++ compiler will inline aggressively enough to sort out the mess?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Mostly the latter - after you go through the `std::function` constructor, it'll be very complex to see through the actual call, especially with small-function optimisations (so you don't actually want devirtualization). Of course *in principle* everything is as-if...

Answer (score 45):

There are two categories.

`auto` can avoid type erasure.  There are unnamable types (like lambdas), and almost unnamable types (like the result of `std::bind` or other expression-template like things).

Without `auto`, you end up having to type erase the data down to something like `std::function`.  Type erasure has costs.

```
std::function<void()> task1 = []{std::cout << "hello";};
auto task2 = []{std::cout << " world\n";};
```

`task1` has type erasure overhead -- a possible heap allocation, difficulty inlining it, and virtual function table invocation overhead.  `task2` has none.  Lambdas *need* auto or other forms of type deduction to store without type erasure; other types can be so complex that they only need it in practice.

Second, you can get types wrong.  In some cases, the wrong type will work seemingly perfectly, but will cause a copy.

```
Foo const& f = expression();
```

will compile if `expression()` returns `Bar const&` or `Bar` or even `Bar&`, where `Foo` can be constructed from `Bar`.  A temporary `Foo` will be created, then bound to `f`, and its lifetime will be extended until `f` goes away.

The programmer may have meant `Bar const& f` and not intended to make a copy there, but a copy is made regardless.

The most common example is the type of `*std::map<A,B>::const_iterator`, which is `std::pair<A const, B> const&` not `std::pair<A,B> const&`, but the error is a category of errors that silently cost performance.  You can construct a `std::pair<A, B>` from a `std::pair<const A, B>`.  (The key on a map is const, because editing it is a bad idea)

Both @Barry and @KerrekSB first illustrated these two principles in their answers.  This is simply an attempt to highlight the two issues in one answer, with wording that aims at the problem rather than being example-centric.

Answer (score 9):

The existing three answers give examples where using `auto` helps [“makes it less likely to unintentionally pessimize”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510183/can-the-use-of-c11s-auto-improve-performance#comment52879624_32510183) effectively making it "improve performance".

There is a flip side to the the coin. Using `auto` with objects that have operators that don't return the basic object can result in incorrect (still compilable and runable) code. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099246/wrong-results-using-auto-with-eigen) asks how using `auto` gave different (incorrect) results using the Eigen library, *i.e.* the following lines

```
const auto    resAuto    = Ha + Vector3(0.,0.,j * 2.567);
const Vector3 resVector3 = Ha + Vector3(0.,0.,j * 2.567);

std::cout << "resAuto = " << resAuto <<std::endl;
std::cout << "resVector3 = " << resVector3 <<std::endl;
```

resulted in different output. Admittedly, this is mostly due to Eigens lazy evaluation, but that code is/should be transparent to the (library) user.

While performance hasn't been greatly affected here, using `auto` to avoid unintentional pessimization might be classified as premature optimization, or at least wrong ;).

Comment: Added the opposite question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415831/can-the-use-of-c11s-auto-deteriorate-performance-or-even-break-the-code