# C++ access object behind iterator in loop

Tags: c++, class, iterator, operator-overloading

I have created a list of objects of a class.

The class has an overloaded ostream << operator to output customer data in a structured way.

What I am trying to do is loop over the list of objects and call cout on the object in the iteration.

Code for the loop is as follows:

```
for (list<Kunde>::iterator it = this->kun_list.begin(); it != this->kun_list.end(); ++it) {
                cout << it << endl;
            }
```

With `Kunde` being the class with the overloaded << operator and `kun_list` being the list of objects of type `Kunde`.

friendly overload within the `Kunde` class:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Kunde& kd) {
    os << "__Kundendaten__" << endl;
    os << "Name: " << kd.vorname << " " << kd.name << endl;
    os << "Geburtsjahr: "<< kd.geburtsjahr << endl;
    os << "Adresse: " << kd.strasse << " " << kd.hausnummer << endl << kd.plz << " " << kd.ort << endl;
    os << "Telefon: " << kd.telefonnummer << endl;
    string fschein = "Nein.";
    if (kd.klasse_a_vorhanden) {fschein = "Ja.";}
    os << "Führerschein Kl. A vorhanden: " << fschein << endl;
    return os;
};
```

The above loop does not work because I am using the list iterator instead of an object of class `Kunde`. I can access members of `Kunde` via `it→member` but how do I use that iterator as reference to the whole object?

Thanks!

Comment: The equivalent of `->` without referencing a member is unary `*`. It works for iterators just like for pointers. (But the answer already has a suggestion that is better than your loop construct anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a const reference loop over the container:

```
for (const auto & kunde : kun_list) {
            cout << kunde << endl;
}
```

Obviously you also have to fix `<<`:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Kunde& kd) {...}
```

Comment: `const` will not work since OP used a non-`const` reference in the `operator<<`. (Of course the latter should be fixed.)

Comment: That's it, thanks to both of you! I will have to wait a few minutes until I can mark as solved.

Comment: worth to notice that ```auto``` can [prevent implicit conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510183/can-the-use-of-c11s-auto-improve-performance)